# Unable to access network share from ubuntu 23.04

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing, network-drive

I have a network drive that I can not access from ubuntu 23.04. When I try to connect to it via new server connection it just sits there with the loading icon and never fails or connects. I can connect to the drive just fine with windows 10 or 11, Mac, and a raspberry pios.I tried to browse to the shared folder but I get a error that says unable to access location failed to retrieve share list from server: invalid argument.

Comment: What operating system and what version of that OS is running on the server?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting